# Nifi executeSql with 30 threads very slow

Tags: oracle, apache-nifi

We are using HDF to fetch large data from oracle. We have a generateTableFetch to create partition of 8000 records which create query like below :

```
Select * from ( Select a.*, ROWNUM rnum FROM (SELECT * FROM OPUSER.DEPENDENCY_TYPES WHERE (1=1))a WHERE ROWNUM <= 368000) WHERE rnum > 361000
```

Now this query is taking almost 20-25min to return from oracle.

Is there anything wrong that we are doing wrong or any configuration changes we can do.

Nifi uses jdbc connection so is there any oracle side configuration for that.

Also if we somehow add parallelism hint to the query example /*parallel(c,2)*/. WIll this help?

Comment: When it comes to performance, always check execution plans. Please provide the execution plan of your query so we can see what Oracle actually does.

Comment: I am not sure how to get execution plan when query is being executed from nifi.

Comment: Can you connect to Oracle via SQL*Plus, SQL Developer or whatever?

Comment: To Pavel's point, you can take the query above and use SQL*Plus or whatever to issue an `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR <your_query_here>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using Oracle 11 (or less) and have selected `Oracle` as the database type. Since LIMIT/OFFSET wasn't introduced until Oracle 12, NiFi uses the nested SELECT with ROWNUM approach to ensure each "page" of data contains unique values. If you are using Oracle 12+, make sure to use the `Oracle 12+` database adapter instead, as it can leverage the LIMIT/OFFSET capabilities resulting in a faster query. Also make sure you have the appropriate index(es) in place to help with query execution.

As of NiFi 1.7.0, you might also consider setting the `Column for Value Partitioning` property. If you have a column (perhaps your `DEPENDENCY_TYPES` column) that is fairly uniformly distributed, and is not "too sparse" in relation to your `Partition Size` property value, GenerateTableFetch can use the column's values rather than the ROWNUM approach, resulting in faster queries. See [NIFI-5143](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5143) and the GenerateTableFetch documentation for more details.

If you need to add hints to the JDBC session, then as of NiFi 1.9.0 (see [NIFI-5780](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5780) for more details) you can add pre- and post-query statements to ExecuteSQL.

Comment: Is it possible to let me know what is the best possible optimised query that be produced for the above query so that i can work on changing the above via executeStreamCommand.

Comment: @SiddharthChaurasia Hi Siddharth, habe you solve your performance issue?